# Get current named outlet from url

Tags: angular, router, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have a route that looks like this :

```
/dashboard/55612291A38AB9CB1C8FE7FB7A166E63/(report//right:logs)
```

which means I have a DashboardComponent, in which I open a ReportComponent inside the primary outlet. In my DashboardComponent, I also have a named outlet (right) in which the LogsComponent is open.

```
<dashboard>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
</dashboard>
```

In my ReportComponent, I'd like to get the value of the current component open in the right outlet. Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Right now it seems to be possible doing

```
this.route.snapshot._urlSegment.parent.children.right.segments[0].path
```

a little bit to verbose.
Thanks.