# Get current outlet name

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following URL:
`http://localhost:6002/S8R4oL_nDk8-/a0_ksrURM10-/inspections/list/(inspection:bulk-assign)`
and what I'm trying to do is to get the outlet name (`bulk-assign`) but I can't find an elegant solution for this.

I just found this one [Get current named outlet from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875267/get-current-named-outlet-from-url) but it's so ugly. Isn't there any other possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I've found is `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.children[0].routeConfig.path`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` contains a property called `outlet`, which seems to be what you're looking for:

```js
export class ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  /** @internal */
  constructor(
      /** The URL segments matched by this route */
      public url: UrlSegment[],
      /* ... */,
      /** The outlet name of the route */
      public outlet: string,
      /* ... */
      ) {}
  /* ... */
}
```

[*Source code*.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L332)